# How can I set the default timezone in python?

Tags: python, timezone

In Java, we can set the default time zone by `-Duser.timezone=GMT+8`.

How can I set the default timezone in python?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this at the start of your code:

```
import os
os.system("tzutil /s \"Central Standard Time\"");
```

This also changes your system's time, so make sure to changeit when finished. Don't know if this will help.